# Add multiple rows to a table using `forEach` without affecting browser performance

Tags: javascript, angular

I generate dynamic table column and rows in a parent component by adding a name from a model (child component).

Parent component HTML.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Words</th>
        <th *ngFor="let wordList of wordList">{{wordList.word}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let keys of workModel">
        <td>{{keys.key}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let translation of keys.translation">
            <input type="text" [name]="keys.key" [(ngModel)]="translation.value">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In service I'm calling this function.

```
addWord( newWordName : string ) {

    const addWord = {
        language: newWordName,
        value: ''
    };

    this._workModel.forEach( ( data : EditorInstance ) => {
        data.translation.push( { ...addWord } );
    } );
}
```

Whenever I add a new word, browser is going to not responsive mode i.e., it hangs the browser. Here `this._workModel` may also contains some values.

Additional thing below.
So I tried implementing `changeDetection`in it parent component.

```
addNewWord( newWord : string ) {

    this.cdr.detach();

    setInterval(() => {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();


    this._translatorEditorService.addLanguage( newLanguage )
        .then( () => {
        } ).catch( () => {
    } );
    }, 5000);
}
```

But Still the same. Is there any other way of implementing to achieve smooth handling of adding the rows in `forLoop`.

Comment: where is "wordList" coming from?

Comment: From child component. I'm just passing a string like a heading to that column

Comment: let wordList of wordList. Try changing the variable name to something different. Just speculating.

Comment: I dont think that is the issue. Anyhow I changed but stil the issue didnt resolved. The problem is with adding dynamic rows(multiple rows) browser is hanging.

Comment: @Nosheep is there is any other way to push to an array?